Simple CNN without pooling layers, differentiability
I need to be able to produce a convolutional neural network where I am able to extract the gradients of the output pixels with respect to the input pixels. I am not really sure if I can do this using pooling layers and so on.
In my use case, the CNN will be taking in input images and trying to match a lithography transformation, while maintaining differentiability with respect to the input pixels. This is very important for something called Inverse Lithography.
So my question is, would a very simple CNN be able to train well to fit this transformation? For instance, could I just have several convolutions. Would that make sense. Thanks.

why not trying it  and seeing if it works?
